# In mikro-orm, Is it possible to track unit of work changes in the afterTransactionCommit hook in explicit transactions?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, mikro-orm

In afterFlush event we receive the changes in entities seeing `uow` arg:

```
async afterFlush(args: FlushEventArgs): Promise<void> {
    args.uow?.getChangeSets()...
```

But in afterTransactionCommit hook `uow` is undefined in the case of explicit transactions (i.e transactional() method)

Is there a way to have this changes when using transactions hooks and explicit transactions?

I would love to have the same behaviour that `afterFlush` event when using `afterTransactionCommit`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an omission in the implementation, but you should have the EntityManager in the there - and you can always access the underlying UoW instance from it.

Keep in mind that the transaction hooks are lower level and can be triggered without the EM as well (but it will be there if you use the EM methods).

Comment: Thanks @MartinAdámekm you are right `args.em` is defined. But `args.em.getUnitOfWork().getChangeSets()` returns an empty array in explicit transactions while in implicit transactions it returns the changes. You can see it in GH1175.tests.ts for example. I don't know if I am missunderstanding something or if it is a bug.

Comment: GH1175 is the worst test in the whole test suite, the most complex one, I always struggle with that one when I have to refactor TX-related stuff, so better not to debug anything on it. It was a community PR, and I hate myself for accepting it in its current shape (very deep nesting, tests that are dependent on each other, etc). Tests should be easy to understand and this one is the very opposite... :]

Comment: I checked the test and the problem here will be that the `afterTransactionCommit` is executed too late, after the UoW state is already cleared. You should be really using the `afterFlush` for this use case, why did you want the other hook?

Comment: The `afterFlush` hook is technically also executed after the TX is committed, see the implementation https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/blob/master/packages/core/src/unit-of-work/UnitOfWork.ts#L396.

Comment: The problem with the `afterTransactionCommit` combined with explicit TX is that it is executed after the `flush` call resolves - so after the UoW state is cleared: https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/blob/master/packages/core/src/EntityManager.ts#L920